# Dirichlet Unit Theorem Application

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, exact-sequence

I am reading these [notes](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/1999/99RubinCM.pdf), and do not quite understand how in the proof of Lemma 9.1, the $ \Delta$-equivariant exact sequence is written.

For the specific case I am concerned about, I assume that $ p $ splits into two parts in $K $, so that $ F/K $ is a cyclic extension of degree $ p - 1 $, $ \Delta = \mathrm{Gal}(F/K)$.  Dirichlet's unit theorem tells us that $   \mathcal{O}_{F}^{\times}\otimes \mathbb{Q} $ is of dimension $ p-2 $. So the dimensions do add up. But how exactly are the maps defined?

Comment: Washington's book gives a definition of the so-called Minkowski unit $ \epsilon $. I am guessing the map would be defined by sending $ \epsilon^{\sigma} $ to $ \sigma $, but I am wondering if I can choose $ \epsilon $ so that the image is the augmentation ideal, but I guess that is not necessary.